# convert data from osm to osm tiles/marble

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I need to convert the raw thata OSM XML to tiles styled like standard OSM tiles (and other styles if possible)

From the research I've done I've found I need to have osm2pgsql and put it on the same server with my data (postGIS or sth), then I can render it with Mapnik using OSM style.

1) Do I have to have a server to convert files?
2) Is there a faster way to do this? (I've found sth about Imposm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no you dont need a server.

you can install postgis on your computer and use osm2pgsql.

i recommend using [tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)
to create the tiles from your postgis db and use 
[osm-bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright)
to style them.

you can then export them from tilemill in number of formats (i use mbtiles - you can open it to see the actual images if you need via [mbutils](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil))

i dont know about a faster way other then downloading the tiles themselves from somewhere..

Comment: osm-bright (carto- that I used) are for style setting when uploading data to db, right? I managed to connect TileMill to db, I added a layer (as described [link](http://www.kindle-maps.com/blog/using-postgis-openstreetmap-data-with-tilemill.html), but there is no data shown (when I look up features- there is a lot of "unknown"). Nevertheless I need to write all the "true styling" in the TileMill (.mss file in box on the right)? I want to simply render the map like it is in osm, I dont Want to play with the styling.

Comment: follow the instructions in the osm-bright link i posted - you dont have to play with the styling - it is there. it adds a project to tillmill that is already styled.

Comment: Is there an another, better way to make png tiles (for marble) than tilemill (it doesn't have option to export to png files- only one png)

Comment: hi, as i said, you can export to mbtiles and then extract it to the actual images via mbutils

Comment: yes, but there is one step more to convert and the data will be hudge (I am trying to download it but it takes weeks (months?) ). I am looking to achieve this with as small nuber of conversion steps as possible. I am trying now with Mapnik on it's own ( I hope that I can get from it same output as downloaded tiles).
[another answer](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7654/creating-png-tiles-for-all-zoom-levels)

Comment: ofc I ment that I want png tiles (maybe my description was a bit fuzzy)